# Troublesome Alert box by yahoo ads

Tags: javascript, jquery, yahoo, ads

How do im able to console/alert out the value of `{PUB_URL}` and `{REQUESTID}` from yahoo ads iframe?

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO" width="300" height="250" src="http://tags1.z5x.net:5280/?ad_type=ad&amp;ad_size=300x250&amp;section=222222&amp;pub_url=${PUB_URL}&amp;ord=${REQUESTID}"></iframe>
```

Im only able to know the `{PUB_URL}` and `{REQUESTID}` value by inspect the element using web developer tool. But, no able to do so at mobile browser. Hence, im want to alert out `{PUB_URL}` and `{REQUESTID}` value. My yahoo ads keep pop-up the alert box in certain ads. Im want to know this troublesome ads detail but no idea how to do.

Im have try to use `$('iframe').contents().html()` but fail because for cross domain issue. 
Any way able to console/alert out the value of `{PUB_URL}` and `{REQUESTID}` by using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[width="300"]'),
    matches = iframe.src.match(/pub_url=([^&]+).*?ord=([^&]+)/);

alert("PUB_URL: " + matches[1] + "\nREQUESTID: " + matches[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Dagg. Appreciate the help :).

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it:

```
var iframe, a, result;
iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
a = document.createElement('a');
result = {};
a.href = iframe.src;
a.search.split('&').forEach(function (e) { 
    var key, val;
    e = e.split('='); 
    key = e.shift().replace('?', ''); 
    val = e.shift();
    result[key] = val;
});
console.log(result);
```